# LDAP, NSLCD, and PAM Auth; Debian 10

Tags: debian, ldap, pam

I may be looking in the wrong place, and if so let me know and I'll find the correct place.

I've been struggling with the issue for the past week or so in my homelab set up. I followed the instructions here: https://devconnected.com/how-to-setup-openldap-server-on-debian-10/ for setting up ldap with debian 10, but I ran into an issue where the walkthrough says to run:
`getent passwd` to return the local and ldap users.

getent passwd is only returning the local users for me.

tail /var/log/auth.log shows a repeat set of lines: (Note, I'm not worried about giving out pii here as it's a homelab.

> pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by crystaladmin(uid=0)
> pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
> pam_ldap(sudo:account): error reading from nslcd: Connection reset by peer

Ok, so pam_ldap & pam_unix are having issues; And checking systemctl status nslcd also shows some errors:

> <authz"crystaladmin"> ldap_result() failed: Invalid DN syntax: invalid DN
> <group/member="root"> ldap_result() failed: Invalid DN syntax: invalid DN

But I can run an ldapsearch and return the ldap results just fine.

I'm more than happy to provide whatever logs or configs are needed, it may just take me some time to get the logs up as I'm a bit awkward getting that stuff out of my cli's still.

Comment: I can't find anything about nslcd on that web page. Why are you using it? Pretty much everyone abandoned it and uses sssd these days.

Comment: libnss-lapd & libnss-lapd both pull nslcd by default in debian, and the tutorial mentions you install one or the other; As to why I wasn't using it; I have nslcd, and my personal experience is fix your current problem before you pull in a new shiny thing. If it comes down to just "nslcd causes stability issues and shouldn't be used because it's depreciated" then fair, but I'm well out of my element so I'm trying to screw with as little things as possible. But I'm more than happy to look into SSSD, in the meantime, that doesn't help me with my current issue